# It looks like you're trying to access functions.config().algolia but there is no value there

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to run firebase emulators for cloud functions, but when I type `firebase emulators:start`, everytime I get this error [image: Error]

I tried setting up functions configuration too as suggested by => https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator . It generates .runtimeconfig.json file. But I am still getting the same error.
[image]

Note that I am a complete beginner in cloud functions.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue and was able to fix it by saving my `.runtimeconfig.json` file with UTF-8 encoding instead of UTF-16 encoding.

The `firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json` command seemed to save it with UTF-16 encoding by default, and the emulator does not like that for some reason.

If using  VScode you can change to UTF-8 by clicking UTF-16 LE in the bottom right of the window. Then just hit save with encoding => UTF-8

[image: change UTF-16 LE to UTF-8]

Comment: This worked for me. After saving the .runtimeconfig.json in UTF-8 format and re-starting the emulator, my functions were working.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. The .runtimeconfig.json should be in the functions directory.

So you have to do `cd functions` and then `firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json`.

Comment: thanks, that was it .

I should have run this command inside functions directory and not the project root .

firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json

Answer (score 3):

I think the part that is impacting you as well, is the `TypeError: Cannot read property` appid `of undefined`. As clarified in this issue on [Github official repository](https://github.com/googlearchive/cloud-functions-emulator/issues/275), you need to run the command `firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json`, after configuring your `algolia.app_id` - which relates to the second error that I mentioned - via the command `firebase functions:config:set algolia.app_id="YOUR_APP_ID"`.

So, first, configure your `app_id` for your Algolia and once you have than that, run the command `firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json`, so you have Algolia well configured in your Cloud Functions and the error is not faced anymore.

Comment: It didn't help but I found a simple hack to make it work. Thanks anyway. Without you it wasn't possible.

Comment: Hi @ShrijanRegmi glad to hear that it helped in the end. Please, consider upvote/accepting it, since it helped you. And feel free to add details for the workaround that you followed. :)

Comment: Hi @gso_grabriel, I have already upvoted it but I think it was my stack overflow reputation that made it invisible here. 

Since `firebase functions:config:set algolia.app_id="YOUR_APP_ID"` did not work for me, I directly placed my algolia app id in my code (hard coded the app id).

Previously it was like :- algoliasearch(functions.config().algolia.appId)
Now I made it :- algoliasearch('MY_APP_ID'),

And yeah, it is not a proper way to do that and while deploying I must not hard code it. Instead of banging my head to solve the problem, I just used this simple hack for now.

Comment: the hard_coding is not good, specially if you source control your files in github or similar remote repositories.
Make sure the generated file (.runtimeconfig.json ) is inside the "functions" subdir and not in the root.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by others, make sure to run this command "inside" functions subdir or move the generated file there.
`firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json`
and that the file has correct encoding.

To verify your functions are reading all configuration correctly, "temporarily" add this line to your code

`functions.logger.warn(functions.config());`

And start the functions emulator. You should see a json output with all the configuration that you have set before. if anything is missing you need to set again then deploy the functions and regenerate the .runtimeconfig.json for emulator.

Answer (score 1):

This is already mentioned in Firebase doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#unix

Use the below command:

```
firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json
```

If using Windows PowerShell, replace the above with:

```
firebase functions:config:get | ac .runtimeconfig.json
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I didn't deploy the functions! you have to deploy first for the `config` data to be available. Once deployed, problem solved.

```
$ firebase deploy --only functions
```

Answer (score 0):

changing

```
 "firebase-tools": "^9.10.2"
```

to

```
 "firebase-tools": "9.10.2"
```

solved the issue.